# What arguments and examples did Newton give in support of Absolute time and space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

As everyone knows, Sir Newton advocated the [Absolute Space & Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_time_and_space) theory. But what examples and arguments did he confer to establish his theory? I read the wiki page where it was written that he gave examples regarding sphere and some sort of that. What did he want to tell by these spheres??

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154882/2451

Comment: What about Newton's bucket and stones?

Comment: Did you read http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#4?.  In reality, of course, Newton'd mind was simply straining against the reality that one could not determine an absolute space with any imaginable method of mechanics. The same psychological problem can be found today in plenty of people who still can't believe that the circle can not be squared or that one can not build a perpetual motion machine. You see this "mind over matter" phenomenon as a universal principle of human thinking (with sometimes horrible consequences).

Answer (score 1):

The model he proposed involved Euclidean geometry and no conversion of time.  In short, there was nothing observed different to how the planets moved, to ordinary cannonball theory.  There was no anomaly for him to think differently.